# dataweave in windows to process ndjson files (x-ndjson does not work)

Tags: json, dataweave, mule4

I work in Windows 10 command line and I have two files json and ndjson:

```
C:\\work\\dev\\dev-handy\>type beat_salary.json
[
 {"s_name":"Richard Starkey", "s_id":"beat01", "s_birth_date":"1940-07-07", "n_salary": 70.07 },
 {"s_name":"John Lennon",     "s_id":"beat02", "s_birth_date":"1940-10-09", "n_salary": 100.09 },
 {"s_name":"Paul McCartney",  "s_id":"beat03", "s_birth_date":"1942-06-18", "n_salary": 60.18 },
 {"s_name":"George Harrison", "s_id":"beat04", "s_birth_date":"1943-02-25", "n_salary": 20.25 }
]

C:\\work\\dev\\dev-handy\>type  beat_salary.ndjson

{"s_name":"Richard Starkey","s_id":"beat01","s_birth_date":"1940-07-07","n_salary":70.07}
{"s_name":"John Lennon","s_id":"beat02","s_birth_date":"1940-10-09","n_salary":100.09}
{"s_name":"Paul McCartney","s_id":"beat03","s_birth_date":"1942-06-18","n_salary":60.18}
{"s_name":"George Harrison","s_id":"beat04","s_birth_date":"1943-02-25","n_salary":20.25}
```

I can process ok the json file:

```
C:\work\dev\dev-handy>  dw run -i file1=beat_salary.json   "%dw 2.0  output application/json  input payload  application/json  --- file1 "
[
  {
    "s_name": "Richard Starkey",
    "s_id": "beat01",
    "s_birth_date": "1940-07-07",
    "n_salary": 70.07
  },
  {
    "s_name": "John Lennon",
    "s_id": "beat02",
    "s_birth_date": "1940-10-09",
    "n_salary": 100.09
  },
  {
    "s_name": "Paul McCartney",
    "s_id": "beat03",
    "s_birth_date": "1942-06-18",
    "n_salary": 60.18
  },
  {
    "s_name": "George Harrison",
    "s_id": "beat04",
    "s_birth_date": "1943-02-25",
    "n_salary": 20.25
  }
]
```

But when I try to process ndjson file with mimetype "application/ndjson"  file I got this error:

```
C:\\work\\dev\\dev-handy\>  dw run -i file1=beat_salary.ndjson   "%dw 2.0  output application/json  input payload  application/ndjson  --- file1 "
\[ERROR\] Error while executing the script:
\[ERROR\] Unknown content type \`application/ndjson\`. Supported content types are: \`application/dw\`, \`application/json\`, \`application/xml\`, \`application/csv\`, \`application/octet-stream\`, \`text/plain\`, \`application/x-www-form-urlencoded\`, \`multipart/form-data\`, \`text/x-java-properties\`, \`application/yaml\`

1| %dw 2.0  output application/json  input payload  application/ndjson  --- file1
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Trace:
  at anonymous::main (line: 1, column: 50) at:

1| %dw 2.0  output application/json  input payload  application/ndjson  --- file1
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And when I try to process ndjson file with mimetype "application/x-ndjson"  file I got this error:

```
C:\\work\\dev\\dev-handy\>  dw run -i file1=beat_salary.ndjson   "%dw 2.0  output application/json  input payload  application/x-ndjson  --- file1 "
\[ERROR\] Error while executing the script:
\[ERROR\] Unknown content type \`application/x-ndjson\`. Supported content types are: \`application/dw\`, \`application/json\`, \`application/xml\`, \`application/csv\`, \`application/octet-stream\`, \`text/plain\`, \`application/x-www-form-urlencoded\`, \`multipart/form-data\`, \`text/x-java-properties\`, \`application/yaml\`

1| %dw 2.0  output application/json  input payload  application/x-ndjson  --- file1
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Trace:
  at anonymous::main (line: 1, column: 50) at:

1| %dw 2.0  output application/json  input payload  application/x-ndjson  --- file1
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How can I process my ndjson file?

this is my dw (for windows) version:

```
C:\\work\\dev\\dev-handy\>dw --version
Command Line : V1.0.34
Runtime : V2.6.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Thanks in advance.

also, I have tried:

```
C:\work\dev\dev-handy>  dw run   "%dw 2.0  output application/json  var my_inp = readUrl(\"file:///c:beat_salary.ndjson\",\"application/ndjson\")   ---  my_inp "
[ERROR] Error while executing the script:
[ERROR] Unknown content type `application/ndjson`. Supported content types are: `application/dw`, `application/json`, `application/xml`, `application/csv`, `application/octet-stream`, `text/plain`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, `text/x-java-properties`, `application/yaml`

1| %dw 2.0  output application/json  var my_inp = readUrl("file:///c:beat_salary.ndjson","application/ndjson")   ---  my_inp
                                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Trace:
  at anonymous::readUrl (line: 1, column: 87)
  at anonymous::main (line: 1, column: 48) at:

1| %dw 2.0  output application/json  var my_inp = readUrl("file:///c:beat_salary.ndjson","application/ndjson")   ---  my_inp
```

And, this way too:

```
C:\work\dev\dev-handy>  dw run   "%dw 2.0  output application/json  var my_inp = readUrl(\"file:///c:beat_salary.ndjson\",\"application/x-ndjson\")   ---  my_inp "
[ERROR] Error while executing the script:
[ERROR] Unknown content type `application/x-ndjson`. Supported content types are: `application/dw`, `application/json`, `application/xml`, `application/csv`, `application/octet-stream`, `text/plain`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, `text/x-java-properties`, `application/yaml`

1| %dw 2.0  output application/json  var my_inp = readUrl("file:///c:beat_salary.ndjson","application/x-ndjson")   ---  my_inp
                                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Trace:
  at anonymous::readUrl (line: 1, column: 87)
  at anonymous::main (line: 1, column: 48) at:

1| %dw 2.0  output application/json  var my_inp = readUrl("file:///c:beat_salary.ndjson","application/x-ndjson")   ---  my_inp
```

Note: I can process the ndjson file with jq tool:

```
C:\work\dev\dev-handy>jq "." beat_salary.ndjson
{
  "s_name": "Richard Starkey",
  "s_id": "beat01",
  "s_birth_date": "1940-07-07",
  "n_salary": 70.07
}
{
  "s_name": "John Lennon",
  "s_id": "beat02",
  "s_birth_date": "1940-10-09",
  "n_salary": 100.09
}
{
  "s_name": "Paul McCartney",
  "s_id": "beat03",
  "s_birth_date": "1942-06-18",
  "n_salary": 60.18
}
{
  "s_name": "George Harrison",
  "s_id": "beat04",
  "s_birth_date": "1943-02-25",
  "n_salary": 20.25
}
```

Note: I know use jq "." -s myfile.ndjson to convert ndjson to json, but I want to avoid this option.

Answer (score 1):

The correct MIME type to use is `application/x-ndjson` as you can see in the [documentation page](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-formats-ndjson).

The problem seems to be that the current version of the `dw` command line tool doesn't support that format. The error tells you which formats are currently supported:

```
`application/dw`, `application/csv`, `application/json`, `multipart/form-data`, `application/octet-stream`, `text/x-java-properties`, `text/plain`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `application/xml`, `application/yaml`
```

It works well in the [DataWeave Playground](https://dataweave.mulesoft.com/learn/).

Comment: Thanks aled, I have seen this file: "ndjson-module-2.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" included in the original zip file. How can I use it?

Comment: The readme says it supports ndjson, so this is probably a bug.